# Oracle 10g recursive count of xml clob

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, count, clob

i am running a Oracle 10gR2 DB and we import xml information and it's stored in a CLOB.  i am trying to get a count of the number of times a phrase 'nIIN' appears in the CLOB and divide by 2.

```
select count(REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec_data, '[=nIIN=]', 'i'))
from gcssmc_imports_data
where interface_name = 'MATS'
and created_date like to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY');
```

above is a query i put together, but I am missing something.

and here is the error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
select count(REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec_data, '[=nIIN=]', 'i')) from gcssmc_imports_data where interface_name = 'MATS' and created_date like to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY')
Error at Command Line:1 Column:13
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `created_date like to_char(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY')` looks totally wrong. Why use `LIKE` without any wildcards. And why is `created_date` not a `DATE` column?

Comment: @user1304011 - If you are "missing something", it would be very helpful to tell us what the query is not doing that you expect it to.  Is it not counting some occurrences that you would expect it to?  Is it not counting some documents entirely?  Is it generating an error?  Like a_horse_with_no_name, I suspect that you want your predicate to compare a date with a date.  If `create_date` is a date, you probably want `create_date = trunc(sysdate)`

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives you the clue you need:

```
Error at Command Line:1 Column:13
```

This refers to this part of the query:

```
1234567890123
select count(REGEXP_SUBSTR(rec_data,
```

The `count` is expecting a number, a string or some other simple datatype. However, REGEXP_SUBSTR here returns a CLOB because that's what it got as its first parameter (rec_data).

I suggest you change your query to use REGEXP_INSTR - which returns 0 if the substring was not found, e.g.:

```
select count(case when REGEXP_INSTR(rec_data, '[=nIIN=]', 'i') = 0
                  then null
                  else 1
             end) ...
```

Comment: ok, so I eddited my query, per answer 1, but now i just recieve a 0.    select count(case when REGEXP_INSTR(rec_data, '[=nIIN=]', 'i') = 0
                  then null
                  else 1
             end) as NIINs
from gcssmc_imports_data
where interface_name = 'MATS'
and status = 'COMPLETED'
and created_date like '02-APR-12';    The XML i wish to count has at least 300 - 400 counts of nIIN.  and I wish to count how many are in the single column and row.

Comment: Ok, but that's another question. There's a few problems with your query, as mentioned in comments above - e.g. the date comparison is probably wrong.